# Воспрос по жизненому циклу приложения

Tags: android, activity-life-cycle

Я использую приложение взаимосвязанное с сервисом, в методе `onDestroy` приложения установлен запуск сервиса с уведомлением.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        i.setAction(Constants.SERVICE.SERVICE_IN_BACKGROUND);
        startService(i);
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

То есть, если пользователь сворачивает приложение, запускается сервис с уведомлением, если вновь разворачивает, то уведомление закрывается.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда приложение свернуто, если очистить его из фоновых приложений, то сервис с уведомлением живет дальше, но так как он был связан с приложением, его функции в уведомлении не работают. Есть ли какой-либо метод который срабатывает когда приложение уничтожается полностью? Чтобы я в нем уничтожал сервис с уведомлением. Например если я свернул приложение и очистил его из фоновых процессов, чтобы вместе с этим уничтожился и сервис?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил:

В файл манифеста где сервис добавил:

```
android:stopWithTask="false"
```

---

```
<service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

В самом сервисе создал метод:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    stopSelf();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`stopService("имя сервиса")` пробовали?

Comment: В пределах обычных методов лайфцикла я могу вызывать или уничтожать его, вопрос в том, как уничтожать в том случае или приложение закрыто в фоновых процессах.

Comment: освежите мне память а разве если приложение в фоне onDestroy вызывается?наскольок я помню он вызывался когда активность убивается а если в фоне то onStop

Comment: Если свернуть приложение оно переходит в состояния от onPause, onStop, onDestroy. Я так же думал, думал если свернуть то onStop а если полностью уничтожить onDestroy, но нет. Я решил уже проблему.

Comment: Согласно документации Google, гарантированно вызывается только `onPause` при сворачивании. А методы `onStop` и `onDestroy` могут вообще не вызываться в определенных условиях.